# Get Location info using Network Service

Tags: windows-phone-8, location, network-service

How to get location information(Latitude,Longitude)using Network service in windows phone8? Not not using gps.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the `latitude` and the `longitude` to an address, you may want to try the `reverse geocoding`using geocode service from bing maps.

You could refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879136.aspx) article.

Have a look at the `Bing` map [services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx)  or the [Google Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)

Hope it helps!